# How to show an array in a list with on/off option react native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have an array to show it in a list along with an on/off Switch. Now the array I have is dynamic and I want the list to get updated accordingly. I want that, if I make a switch Off, that field in details should not be visible and vice versa in case of switching on. This is the array I have -

```
"piDetail": {
      "cCode1": "Unique code",
      "cCode2": "Brand Code",
      "cCode3": "Pattern Code",
      "cCode4": "Assortment Code",
      "cCode5": "Size Code",
      "cCode6": "COLOR Code",
      "cName1": "UniqueCode Name",
      "cName2": "Brand NAme",
      "cName3": "Pattern Name",
      "cName4": "Assortment Name",
      "cName5": "Size Name",
      "cName6": "COLOR Name",
      "calculatedMargin": "Calculated Margin",
      "deliveryDate": "Delivery Date",
      "desc2Code": "Section Code",
      "desc2Name": "Section Name",
      "desc3Code": "Fabric Code",
      "desc3Name": "Fabric Name",
      "desc4Code": "Other Code",
      "desc4Name": "Other Name",
      "desc5Code": "Weaved Code",
      "desc5Name": "Weaved Name",
      "design": "DESIGN",
      "gst": "GST",
      "hl1Code": "Division Code",
      "hl1Name": "Division Name",
      "hl2Code": "Section Code",
      "hl2Name": "Section Name",
      "hl3Code": "Department Code",
      "hl3Name": "Department Name",
      "hl4Code": "Article Code",
      "hl4Name": "Article Name",
      "hsnSacCode": "HSNCODE",
      "imUDFDate01": "IMUDFDATE01",
      "imUDFDate02": "IMUDFDATE02",
      "imUDFDate03": "IMUDFDATE03",
      "imUDFDate04": "IMUDFDATE04",
      "imUDFDate05": "IMUDFDATE05",
      "imUDFNum01": "IMUDFNUM01",
      "imUDFNum02": "IMUDFNUM02",
      "imUDFNum03": "IMUDFNUM03",
      "imUDFNum04": "IMUDFNUM04",
      "imUDFNum05": "IMUDFNUM05",
      "imUDFString01": "IMUDFSTRING01",
      "imUDFString010": "IMUDFSTRING10",
      "imUDFString02": "IMUDFSTRING02",
      "imUDFString03": "IMUDFSTRING03",
      "imUDFString04": "IMUDFSTRING04",
      "imUDFString05": "IMUDFSTRING05",
      "imUDFString06": "IMUDFSTRING06",
      "imUDFString07": "IMUDFSTRING07",
      "imUDFString08": "IMUDFSTRING08",
      "imUDFString09": "IMUDFSTRING09",
      "intakeMargin": "Intake Margin",
      "marginRule": "Margin Rule",
      "mrp": "MRP",
      "mrpEnd": "End MRP",
      "mrpStart": "Start MRP",
      "netAmountTotal": "Net Amount Total",
      "noOfSets": "Number Of Sets",
      "orderId": "ORDERID",
      "otb": "OTB",
      "quantity": "Quantity",
      "rate": "Rate",
      "ratios": "Ratio",
      "remarks": "Remarks",
      "rsp": "RSP",
      "smUDFDate01": "SMUDFDATE01",
      "smUDFDate02": "SMUDFDATE02",
      "smUDFDate03": "SMUDFDATE03",
      "smUDFDate04": "SMUDFDATE04",
      "smUDFDate05": "SMUDFDATE05",
      "smUDFNum01": "SMUDFNUM01",
      "smUDFNum02": "SMUDFNUM02",
      "smUDFNum03": "SMUDFNUM03",
      "smUDFNum04": "SMUDFNUM04",
      "smUDFNum05": "SMUDFNUM05",
      "smUDFStrin01": "SMUDFSTRIN01",
      "smUDFStrin010": "SMUDFSTRIN010",
      "smUDFStrin02": "SMUDFSTRIN02",
      "smUDFStrin03": "SMUDFSTRIN03",
      "smUDFStrin04": "SMUDFSTRIN04",
      "smUDFStrin05": "SMUDFSTRIN05",
      "smUDFStrin06": "SMUDFSTRIN06",
      "smUDFStrin07": "SMUDFSTRIN07",
      "smUDFStrin08": "SMUDFSTRIN08",
      "smUDFStrin09": "SMUDFSTRIN09",
      "tax": "Tax",
      "totalAmount": "Basic Amount",
      "typeOfBuying": "Type Of Buying"
    }
```

Now this is how I am showing [image]

For example I have section off then section should be hidden in this screen [image]

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

At first I think you should modify your array, it should contain its state.

You can archive that with

```
array = array.map((item) => {
    return {
         item: item,
         isHidden: true
    }
})
```

Then set your switch state base on your item `isHidden` property.

Hope that help.